# Is Code generate activity diagrams based on Windows Workflow Foundation a good idea?

Tags: workflow-foundation, activity-diagram

I graphically draw Activity Diagrams for (non IT) management .  Knowing that these will finally result in code, as a programmer, I would prefer to write the code directly and generate the diagrams based on the code. Even if I probably won't be coding the application.  Just sounds like a fun thing to do.

I live in a Microsoft, CSharp environment and happy with it.  I have, little experience with Windows Workflow Foundation, but I have a solid understanding of workflows.

First question : Is this way of thinking productive, or should I stick to drawing ?
Second question : Could Windows Workflow Foundation do it or are there better  alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WF 4.5 designer to create a workflow but also it consists of some code either inside the workflow designer to define behavior or in the backyard by creating custom activities..

You can use windows workflow `ActivityBuilder` to serialize or desalinize workflows, so you can create your sketches any other way then serialize them to XAML and create a  workflow file.

here is a [definitive documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/serializing-workflows-and-activities-to-and-from-xaml) on workflow serialization.

Comment: Hello, have you worked with  WF 4.5 designer to create an Activity diagram yourself ?  Based on your answer I would conclude that creating an Activity diagram from code is not a way to go in WWF.